# How to clone a azure repo from azure pipeline?

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-automation

I am trying to clone azure repo using git command 
`git clone https://{userName}:{password}@dev.azure.com/<Organization>/<Project>/_git/<repoName> <local destianation>` This work fine in my local machine.

But when I run this in the azure pipeline I got an error 'clone into ..' error.

What mistake I am doing?

Comment: Thank you Shayki Abramczyk. I tried as they mentioned in the above link. Command executed successfully without any error. But where this cloned repo will get stored?

Comment: In the command-line task you can `cd` to a folder before the clone, or specify a working directory.

Comment: I am running this command in azure pipeline inline script. Is this a right approach?

Comment: Yes, it's perfect. just add a line of `cd path/to/your/folder` before the `git clone`

Comment: you mean my local folder or new folder in the azure repo. I tried creating a new folder in the azure repo and used cd <new folder name> am I correct.